# Actionscript 3: How to have a keyboard Keystroke "Button" go to specific Frame FROM a specific Frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, keyboard-events, keystroke

I'm Super New to Programming in general and very New to Actionscript 3. It's been a rough but fun ride.

Anyway For the work I am doing I have my animation Play up to a certain point and it asks the viewer a question, The viewer has 3 choices, and each of those choices are connected to a button on the keyboard. A B C or D.

After searching for someone with a similar problem, My solution so far is this:

```
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, cNote);
function cNote(event:KeyboardEvent):void {

    trace(event.keyCode);

    if (event.keyCode==67) {
        gotoAndPlay(21);
    }
```

I have this repeated 4 times each for the different Keys.

This works and allows me to move the viewer to the Frame with their response, however Any time during the animation they can press the button and it will move them to the Frame of the corresponding button (in this case Frame 21). How do I set it so that the keypress will only respond and move them to Frame 21 when they are on Frame 20 for example? (I suspect it has something to do with the "stage" part in the code but I cant get it to work without it.)

I also have the audio for the animation on a separate Layer and even though the visuals change as it goes to the correct frame, the audio continues as if the key was not pressed. Is there also a way to connect the key to make it stop the current audio and then play the new audio? Or is there a better way to do this?

Sorry if this is confusing. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It has been quite awhile since I touch flash. From what I remembered, you can click on the frame at your movieclip, insert a keyframe by pressing f6, and press f9 to insert the listener at that frame and that frame only, after an input has been pressed, you remove it. for example:

```
if (event.keyCode==67) {
        gotoAndPlay(21);
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, cNote);
    }
```

For the audios, I usually plays them using code, but I'm quite sure there's a way to drag and drop the audio from library to the movieclip. so I can do sound1.play(), when a button is pressed, I can do sound1.close() and sound2.play()

For more reference:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html